# use computed Field in QWeb in kanban view odoo8

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8

I have a computed filed in my model :

```
initiatives_count = fields.Integer(compute=count_init)
```

when I am trying to use this filed in the QWeb kanban view like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" t-if=" record.initiatives_count.value != 0 ">
```

it gives me that error:

> Uncaught Error: QWeb2 - template['kanban-box']: Runtime Error:
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

so any one have any idea where it goes wrong ????

Comment: it says coun instead of count?

Comment: sorry I have edited my code but I have the same error

Comment: Have you restarted the odoo service and refreshed the module again?

Comment: yes when I Use `record.field.value` for another it work fine

Comment: Maybe it is because its a function field. Try to add in the .py the parameter "store=True":

fields.Integer(compute=count_init, store=True)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have find where I have go wrong that error because I did not define the fields that I will use in the view before using it like this:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="amad_kanban_view_perspective">
    <field name="name">perspective Kabana</field>
    <field name="model">perspective</field>
    <field name="priority">10</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <kanban>
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="initiatives_count"/>
            <field name="initiatives"/>
            <templates>
                <t t-name="kanban-box">
                </t>
            </templates>
        </kanban>
    </field>
</record>
```